# ActionScript - Overriding Method Without Matching Signature?

Tags: actionscript-3, methods, overriding

when extending a class, is it impossible to override a method without also matching the parameters?

for example, i'd like to use the method's name, in this case it's a socket extension and the method i want to override is `connect`.  however, i want to request additional parameters that the stock `connect` function does not request.

is the only alternative to create my own connect-like method with my own parameters, call `super.connect` from this function and override the stock connect function to throw an error if it's called?

that all kind of sounds like a train wreck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[*Function overloading*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_overloading) is not supported in ActionScript (however Darron Schall demonstrated some kind of *pseudo overloading* in [this article](http://www.darronschall.com/weblog/2003/09/method-overloading-in-actionscript-2.cfm)).

I think in your case it's only left over to create your own `connectEx` method.

Comment: by "overloading" do you mean overriding a method with additional parameters?

Comment: @TDI1978: Right. I mean function overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, overloading is not supported.  As a next best option, you could consider optional arguments.  This would allow you to pass as few or as many params as you want to a method.  The method would receive these params in an array and you could handle them however you want from that point on.

Here's how a method using optional params would look:

```
function someMethod(...params):void
{
    for(var i:int = 0 ; i < params.length ; i++ )
    {
        trace("parameter: " + params[i]);
    }
}
```

You can read more about [optional parameters here](http://www.as3dtk.com/?p=420).